# How old was L in the Death Note series?

Tags: death-note

In the Death Note series, it is seen that while L and Soichiro Yagami are observing Light through the cameras, L says that he used to do a lot of pointless things at the age of seventeen.

> [image]

Later, we see that he is giving the same exam as Light, who is seventeen years old at that time.

> [image]

This made me curious. What exactly is L's age?

Comment: L joined Kira's school under a false identity, so he likely lied about his age too. Him looking older than the average student is one of the *less* strange thing about him.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As stated in the [wikia](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/L_(character)), L's age is 24-25 years old.

Also, in [Death Note 13: How to Read](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_13:_How_to_Read), it is stated that L was born on October 31, 1979 and died on November 5, 2004. From this we can calculate that L was 25 years old at the time of his death.

> [image]